# How to import a CSV with Windows Task Scheduler or schedule a task using the command prompt

Tags: mysql, csv, import, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I could run the following command:

```
mysql.exe -u root

use testdb

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/user1/test.csv' INTO TABLE demo FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

under `c:\xampp\mysql\bin`

How could I run the above command as a batch file at task scheduler or schedule task using command prompt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to use `mysql -h host -u user < batch-file`

And store every command in batch-file.